# Cannot convert value class net.sf.saxon.tinytree.TinyElementImpl of type element(transactionDate, xs:anyType) to class java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, templates, xslt, saxon

We have a use-case where we are calling java static methods from Xslt template. We are passing some arguments in the method call. One of the argument is java.util.Date. During testing, I am seeing this particular exception :

`Cannot convert value class net.sf.saxon.tinytree.TinyElementImpl of type element(transactionDate, xs:anyType) to class java.util.Date`

Could not find anything why it's failing.

Java Object :

```
   public Double getValue(String s1, String s2, Date d1) {
    // perform some operation.
    Double response = 2.0;
    return response;
   }
```

Xslt template : Added :

```
   <xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:barcode="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        xmlns:internal="http://internal.project.org"
        xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
        xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
        extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
        xmlns:util="java:com.personal.utils.DateUtil"
        version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="country1" select="/data/country"/>
    <xsl:variable name="country2" select="'US'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="orderDate" select="/data/transactionDate"/>
    <xsl:variable name="currencyToPrint">
            <xsl:value-of select="getValue($country1, $country2, $orderDate)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Can someone please help what is causing this exception, why it's not able to convert to java.util.Date ?

Comment: Does it work if you use `<xsl:variable name="orderDate" select="/data/transactionDate/xs:date(.)"/>`? Needs the namespace declaration `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` obviously in the XSLT code.

Comment: Also, which version and edition of Saxon do you use? With EE you should also be able to use a schema to declare the type `xs:date` for the `transactionDate` element.

Comment: But, this seems to a better way to define this variable in dateTime datatype :
<xsl:variable name="orderDate" as="xs:dateTime" select="/labelData/shipmentInfo/transactionDate"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are given here:

https://saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!extensibility/functions/converting-args/converting-arguments

and here:

https://saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!extensibility/functions/converting-args/converting-atomic

There is no conversion defined from untyped atomic values to `java.util.Date`. There are conversions available from `xs:date` and `xs:dateTime` to `java.util.Date`, so if you first convert `$orderDate` to one of these types, it should work.

Of course, this assumes that /data/transactionDate is in the correct format for an `xs:date` or `xs:dateTime` - if not (for example if it's in D/M/Y format), then you will need to do the conversion yourself.

Comment: Used this to declare the variable <xsl:variable name="orderDate" as="xs:dateTime" select="/labelData/shipmentInfo/transactionDate"/>